# Find the sequence in the String matches the items in the List

Tags: java, string, list, sequence

Suppose I have a list and then I add names to the list

```
List<String> listOfName = new ArrayList();
listOfName.add("abc");
listOfName.add("pqr");
listOfName.add("xyz");
```

And I have a String `String names = "abc\r\npqr\r\nxyz";`

I want to verify that the string is comprised in the same order as the elements in the list are.

eg: abc should come first then pqr and then xyz

What I am trying to do:

```
int flag = 1;
for(int i=0; i<listOfName.size()-1;i++){
    if(names.replace("\r\n","").split(listOfName.get(i))[1].indexOf(listOfName.get(i+1))!=0){
        flag = 0;
        break;
    }
}
if(flag==1){
    System.out.println("True");
} else {
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

Is there any better solution for doing the same as I doubt that it might fail in some scenarios

Comment: Any example of an attempt you made?

Comment: You could check if a whitespace-separated `String` representation of the items of the list is equal to the `String names`... What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited my post @k88

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is certainly a more "abstract" and semantically pretty way to do this:

```java
public class CompareList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listOfNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfNames.add("abc");
        listOfNames.add("pqr");
        listOfNames.add("xyz");
        
        String names = "abc\r\npqr\r\nxyz"; // define string
        boolean match = checkList(listOfNames, names, "\r\n"); //check match
        System.out.println(match); //print match
    }
    
    private static boolean checkList(
            List<String> list,
            String content,
            String delimiter) {
        
        return Arrays.asList(
                content.split(Pattern.quote(delimiter))).equals(list);
    }
    
}
```

This will print `true`.

Here you have method `checkList()` (or whatever name you like) that splits the string using the given delimiter (`\r\n` in your case), turns the resulting array into a `List` and just calls `equals()` on it to compare it with the input `List`, as the `equals()` implementation of `List` (i quote) *"Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal."*.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) for this purpose by creating a `String` from the list of items and put a (Windows-) linebreak (`\r\n`) as delimiter. Then check if it is equal to the `String names`, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listOfName = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfName.add("abc");
    listOfName.add("pqr");
    listOfName.add("xyz");
    
    String names = "abc\r\npqr\r\nxyz";
    
    //  create a linebreak-separated String from the items of the list
    String listItems = String.join("\r\n", listOfName);

    /*
     *  and compare it to the String that might contain those items
     *  in the order they appear in the list 
     */
    if (listItems.equals(names)) {
        System.out.println(listItems + "\r\n== equals ==\r\n"+ names);
    } else {
        System.err.println(listItems + "\r\n!= is not equal to !=\r\n" + names);
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
abc
pqr
xyz
== equals ==
abc
pqr
xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Java 8

```
String names = listOfName.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\r\n"));
```

Documentation of `Collectors.joining` -

> Returns a Collector that concatenates the input elements, separated by
> the specified delimiter, in encounter order.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
List<String> listOfName = new ArrayList<>();
listOfName.add("abc");
listOfName.add("pqr");
listOfName.add("xyz");
String names = "abc\r\npqr\r\nxyz";
System.out.println(String.join("\r\n", listOfName).equals(names));
```

output

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list into an array and then use [`Arrays.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) to compare it with the array obtained after splitting the string on `\r\n`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listOfName = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfName.add("abc");
        listOfName.add("pqr");
        listOfName.add("xyz");

        String names = "abc\r\npqr\r\nxyz";
        String[] namesArr = names.split("\r\n");

        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(namesArr, listOfName.toArray()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

A working example here:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listOfName = new ArrayList();
    listOfName.add("abc");
    listOfName.add("pqr");
    listOfName.add("xyz");

    String names = "abc\r\npqr\r\nxyz";
    String[] splitted_names = names.split("\r\n");

    boolean noNameFound = true;
    for (String name : splitted_names) {
      if (listOfName.contains(name)) {
        System.out.println("Found name " + name + " in listOfName! ");
        noNameFound = false;
      } 
    }
    if (noNameFound) {
          System.out.println("No name found that matched");
    }

  }
}
```